# ASP.NET MVC Grid Display solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I realize there are several solutions to this problem. I am looking for advice on an elegant way to solve a few issues..

I am using Entity Framework for my model.

I need to display tables of data with paging and sorting as minimum functionality.

Before switching to MVC, in WebForms, I was a big fan of the jQuery Datatables plugin..and I used this, with success, alongside a custom parser class to handle paging sorting and filtering. I have now run into a problem using this method with EF

My question is, is there a preferred method to handle Grids in MVC with paging and sorting functionality...

So far I am aware of the following possible solutions:

1. **jQuery Datatables plugin** with some more custom parser work(I would need some help getting started in the right direction with this)
2. **jqGrid**..I understand that there is an open source version as well as a paid version which seems to include a server side solution for MVC
3. **MVCContrib Grid**...I dont know much about this and I am not even sure if this is still an accepted solution.
4. **Telerik MVC Controls** (as suggested in answers below)...seems to be the most popular choice so far...

My main concern is reusability. I would like a solution flexible enough to handle any model/viewmodel I pass in with a minimum amount of custom code. I often run into a situation where I need to display only a few properties of a particular model or need to display properties from a related class(I.E Product.ProductName, Product.ProductCategory.CategoryName)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have decided to try out the Telerik MVC Grid for now. I have high hopes for the **jQuery-UI Grid** that is currently in development. I hope there will be support for ASP.NET MVC considering MS is a sponsor. What I gather from the jQuery site is that their Grid control will be inspired by all the best aspects of the most popular grid controls, including the ones mentioned above. Fingers crossed...

Comment: I would like to prefer jQuery Datatables plugin as This is an awesome plugin for display tabular data with paging, sorting, filtering etc.
Here you can find step by step tutorial with full functionality like paging, sorting, filtering and CRUD operation.... http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/11/implement-jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would take a good look at the Telerik MVC open source components.

[Telerik demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/)

If you bind your grids to IQueryable you also get paging, sorting, filtering and grouping straight out of the box. Their editor component is pretty cool as well.

Comment: +1 - Telerik products are excellent. However, @stephen776, be aware that the free version of the product is licensed under GPLv2. This may not be what you want (particularly if you are using the products for a company you work for). Just wanted to give you a heads up.

Comment: what caveats does the GPLv2 present for using these controls on projects for a company?

Comment: @stephen776 - If you are using it for a company project, you have to also open source your company's code. (If you buy the site license from Telerik, this restriction does not apply.)

Answer (score 3):

Some help with DataTables:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JQuery-DataTables-MVC.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVC-CRUD-DataTable.aspx

Comment: If you are wanting to use DataTables in .NET, you can use my library to bind it to IQueryable: github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik MVC components seem pretty decent - they're based off jQuery and are fairly lightweight in the html they generate.  The MVC components are free and open source - you can even get them off nuget.  They do have a support license that costs money and most of their other stuff isn't free, but the MVC ones are.