# jqgridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Is there any documentaiton for [jqgridview](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGridView)? Is it not used anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqgridview - It appears to be an abandoned project. The author's website (creamarketing.net) produces php errors. The latest commit to jQuery is Nov. 2007. The [author's account](http://plugins.jquery.com/users/victorbartel/track) hasn't done anything else on jQuery's website since.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you may be looking for...

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=15

jqGrid is still a very popular jQuery grid plugin.

Comment: @stephen776 :I think jqgridview is different from jqgrid, isn't it?

Comment: oops my fault..I think you may be correct. jqGrid is still a great solution though...if your looking for something MVC specific, try the Telerik MVC controls...they are free and have an extremely robust and easy to use Grid control built for mvc with jquery

Comment: see my recent question regarding grids in MVC... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554970/asp-net-mvc-grid-display-solutions/5555062#5555062

Comment: @stephen776: Looks like we need to purchase Telerik MVC controls, are you sure they are free?

Comment: @sharma @stephen776 - As I said in the other post, Telerik is great, but remember that their free version license is GPLv2 - it may not be what you want depending on your project. (stephen776 - I put the response in your post as to why you may not want to use the free version.)

Comment: @JasCav: Is there any opensource for MVC apart from mvc-contrib, that we can use jqueries and ajax for good feel and look?

Comment: @sharma - As stephen776 said in his response, you could go ahead and use a jQuery plug-in. This doesn't destroy the MVC paradigm (and can play very nicely with it). In addition, in .NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 3, Microsoft included their own grid control, so you may want to take a look at that.

Comment: meh...doesnt it just feel wrong to use the term "control" when speaking in terms of asp.net MVC lol